# equivalent to foreach loop for just one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

I have a PHP function that runs a SELECT Query in SQL:

```
if(!function_exists("SelectQuery")) {
    function SelectQuery ($sql) {
        global $conn;
        $SelectQuery = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        return $NumRows=mysql_num_rows($SelectQuery);
        $SelectQuery_Results=array();
        while($SelectQuery_Row = mysql_fetch_array($SelectQuery)) {
            $SelectQuery_Results[] = $SelectQuery_Row;
        }
        return $SelectQuery_Results;
    }
}
```

then i am calling it here:

```
$sql="SELECT * from tickets where ticketnumber = '".$_GET["seq"]."' ";
$ticket = SelectQuery($sql);
foreach($ticket as $ticket2) {

}
```

rather than using a `foreach` loop what else could i use as my query will only be returning one row and i dont want to put my whole page within a loop

i tried just removing the `foreach` loop but that didnt work

Comment: `$ticket[0][...]`...?!

Comment: Also, your function shouldn't return any results at all, only a row count.

Comment: You're also vulnerable to SQL injection. [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: there is no ability for user input

Comment: `$_GET` *is* user input.

Comment: well its only myself using this so nothing will happen

Comment: @deceze I wish I could +100 your comment. Getting in the habit of writing secure code will make you a better programmer. Make it secure to start with so that when the time comes when it needs to be transferred or access granted to others it is already secure. And anything web facing should have secure code no matter if you will be the only user or not. What if someone finds your site and tries injection??

Comment: i highly doubt someone will find it, its just a control panel thats used locally

Comment: @charlie `highly doubt` sounds like some uncertainty, and that is just what a hacker needs to own your entire server/network. And control panel at that! I would be very careful what this control panel controls if it is not secure.

Comment: i said its used locally, its physically impossible for anyone to get to it as there is no internet connection to the computer that its running on

Answer (score 1):

Just access your value as `$ticket[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

A function cannot return two values for a single call. So, remove

```
return $NumRows=mysql_num_rows($SelectQuery);
```

You can check the ***array size*** for the **number of rows** in result.

If you want to echo out the result the following code will be ok!

```
if( sizeof($ticket) > 1 ){
    foreach($ticket as $ticket2){
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($ticket2)/2; $i++)
            echo "[" . $ticket2[$i] . "]";
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

$ticket is an integer see :

```
 return $NumRows=mysql_num_rows($SelectQuery);
```

So you juste have to use $ticket.

If you want the row, remove this useless return in the SelectQuery function and use $ticket[0] for the first and only row.

Change the function with this :

```
function SelectQuery ($sql) {
    global $conn;
    $SelectQuery = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
    $NumRows=mysql_num_rows($SelectQuery);
    $SelectQuery_Results=array();
    if ($numRows>1) {
        while($SelectQuery_Row = mysql_fetch_array($SelectQuery)) {
            $SelectQuery_Results[] = $SelectQuery_Row;
        }
    }
    else $SelectQuery_Results = mysql_fetch_array($SelectQuery);
    return $SelectQuery_Results;
    }
```

Then use :

```
 $sql="SELECT * from tickets where ticketnumber = '".$_GET["seq"]."' ";
 $ticket = SelectQuery($sql);
 if (is_array($ticket)) { foreach loop; }
 else { use directly ticket['attribute'] }
```

Comment: so what do i need when i call my function. just use $ticket = SelectQuery($sql); then echo $ticket["column1"]; and so on?

Comment: no because SelectQuery return rows as array, even if only one row, because of the while in the function. Use $ticket[0]; but remove the useless first return

Comment: so how can i echo the database results when i call the function?

Comment: use $ticket2 = $ticket[0]; echo $ticket2['column1']; or look at my edited answer

Comment: ok i have done it as $ticket=SelectQuery($sql); and $ticket = $ticket[0]; how do i echo mysql_num_rows - i tried mysql_num_rows($ticket) but thats not working

Comment: mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql,$conn))

Comment: nope still the same error - Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1

Comment: i tried $num=mysql_num_rows($SelectQuery); in the function then i tried to echo $num; when i called the function but still nothing

Comment: you have helped me this far... lol

Comment: why bother trying to answer if you only use PDO